# Error on POST FiDDLER

Tags: c#, sql, rest

This is the error i get from the JSON TAB in Fiddler

> ExceptionMessage=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__product__9F8A5DAA2DC12F46'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.product'. The duplicate key value is (13                            ).
>   The statement has been terminated.

The command i enter in the body is

> {"ib_itemcode1":"13                ","transtatuscode":"13","invtid":"14                            ","descr":"13                                                          "}

This is my function which i think it should correct.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] product productrecord)
    {
        try
        {
            using (estocktakeEntities entities = new estocktakeEntities())
            {
                entities.products.Add(productrecord);
                entities.SaveChanges();

                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, productrecord);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + productrecord.ib_itemcode1.ToString());
                return message;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

This is in my database SQL

[image]

this is my db

[image]

i wanted to add another item that share the same ib_itemcode1.

how do i go about this?

Comment: Do you know about PK (Primary Key) Constraint ?

Comment: @gypsyCoder yes i know that there can not have 2 same PK, i am adding 2 different pk with the same ib_itemcode1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Adding the product in this line

```
entities.products.Add(productrecord);
```

Check if the product which you are going to add is already available or not. If already available, update it instead of add.
If not available then add it.

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint"

ERROR appears when you have the same item in the primary key and you are trying to add a new record with the same key. Check it.

To Update, you can try with this below line as you are using entity framework.

```
 entities.Entry(productrecord).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
 entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: .state? do i need to import anything?

Comment: ".State" is the property used in entity framework to define the current state for a specific entity.